# How to convert a char * starting with "\0" to unsigned int?

Tags: c++, string, int

I have a problem where i have string "\005" which i need to convert to unsigned int value of 5. What is the best way to do it ?

This is to get the response value from a curl response.

```
int main()
{

    char *ptr = "\005";
    stringstream strValue;
    strValue << *ptr;

    unsigned int intValue;
    strValue >> intValue;

    cout << ptr << endl;
    cout << intValue << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Expect the output to be 5 but getting

0

Comment: Isn't it obvious? `unsigned int n=*ptr;`?

Comment: Do you have a string `\005` (i.e. with actual backslash in the first place) or `[NUL]05` (i.e. first character is ASCII `0`) byte)?

Comment: `int intvalue = 5;` will do it. For a more useful answer you’ll need to explain what each character in that string means, that is, how is the value encoded? How would the value 6 be encoded? 10? 33?

Comment: "This is to get the response value from a curl response." - I understood that "\005" is the string from http response. So it will need parsing to get 5

Comment: You’re trying to interpret the (unprintable) character whose encoding is the number five as if it were a digit.  (The behaviour is as if you had written `char ptr[] = {5, 0};`.)

Answer (score 1):

> How to convert a char * starting with "\0" to unsigned int?
>
> ```
> "\005"
> ```

The string `"\005"` does not begin with the character `'\0'`. It begins with the character `'\005'`, which is an octal escape sequence representing the octal number 005 which is 5 in decimal representation. You can convert the character to `unsigned int` type like this:

```
unsigned int n = ptr[0];
```

P.S. `char *ptr = "\005"` is ill-formed since C++11, because a string literal is not implicitly convertible to a non-const pointer to char.